# Exception occurred in exception handler code: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/... that could accept the message

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I cannot figure out why it can't find this service endpoint.  The service resides in another project in the same solution as my web project.  Apparently this is working for other devs, but I find that hard to believe, I followed some steps they gave me, downloaded the site from svn, yada yada.  When I run the website, it's not finding and resolving this service.

Here's what it looks like in the web.config when I have registered the service there.  This is existing config text that supposedly works for localhost:

```
<client>

  <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/WcfBusinessService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="PipeBestPerformance" contract="WcfBusinessFacadeContract.IBusinessFacade" />

</client>
```

Comment: Yes, I have configured the solution to run the service project first before the web project...in the solution properties

Comment: Umm...actually...obviously your service isn't running. Please include the entire '<system.serviceModel>' for both the service and the client. It is likely that there is a mismatch somewhere.

Comment: No it is running.  If I F5 the solution runs the service and then first up the browser.

Comment: again please include the entire <system.serviceModel> on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have net.pipe enabled in IIS.  Open IIS Manager, right-click on your site and select "Manage Web Site" -> "Advanced Settings".  Look at the "Enabled Protocols" setting.  I'm guessing it probably is set to "http".  If so, change it to "http,net.pipe" and try your application.